# Why Can't I Enable Tab Completion For JSX With Emmet In Atom IDE

Tags: autocomplete, jsx

I'm referring to the instructions at `https://gist.github.com/ivan-hilckov/a487b21b325441cdbe8c56594a685ec0` But, they're not working for me.

My `package.json` file is:

```
{
  "name": "atom-ide-setup",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.6.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.6.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1"
  }
}
```

Atom has the following Community Packages installed:

```
emmet
language-babel
language-javascript-jsx (disabled)
atom-ternjs (disabled)
javascript-snippets
```

My `keymap.cson` file includes:

```
'atom-text-editor[data-grammar~="jsx"]:not([mini])':
  'tab': 'emmet:expand-abbreviation-with-tab'
```

And the `.js` file I'm editing looks like:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      div.myclass  // this doesn't tab expand
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

I suspect I'm missing something, or something is turned off. But I don't know what. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to comments from mikedklein and swelet on another related post. As of Emmet 2.4.3 `command+shift+e` works, or adding:

`'atom-text-editor:not([mini])':'tab': 
  'emmet:expand-abbreviation-with-tab'`

to the keymap.cson file found at Atom -> Keymap... in the menu. Yes, including the single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue using emmet with Atom. What worked for me (on windows) is Ctrl + e